# Can you mirror bitbucket repos with REST API?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm looking to sync two repos in different locations so the destination repo will always match the origin repo. This command can be done through git clone --mirror and git push --mirror. I was wondering how to do this with the REST API since I will be running this on lambda